# React native docs on github

Tags: react-native

I want a copy of the react native docs https://facebook.github.io/react-native/

but a quick look at the github https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/docs

shows that the current docs are not from the master branch.

How can i get an offline copy of the docs that i can run entirely offline?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/0.44-stable/docs go to the branch

Comment: Probably wrong because i can't locate index.md